# default argument in recursive class method of python

Tags: python, recursion, parameter-passing

Inside a recursive class function, how do i use a class member as default argument?

I am currently using following snippet that works (python 3). ***height*** is recursive class function. Default argument that i want to use for *node* is *self._root*. In order to achieve this, i do something like following but thats a very round about way where i have to define another function ***height_tree***. Is there a more direct approach?

```
# following code works #  

class BTree: 

    def __init__(self, node=None):
        self._root = node

    def height_tree(self):
        return self.height(self._root)

    def height(self, node):
        if node is not None:
            height = max(self.height(node.get_left()), self.height(node.get_right())) + 1
        else:
            height = 0
        return height
```

I want to do something like following but it obviously doesn't works !

```
def height(self, node=self._root)
   # code from above follows
```

I however cannot use alternate trick of assigning root to node when node is None since that is one of the end condition in recursion

```
def height(self, node)
    if node is None:
       node = self._root
    # this will conflict with logic in code block above#
```

Are there any recommended ways to handle such a situation?

Comment: I'd say using a helper method is already the most elegant way to go about it. You could call the methods `height` and `_height` instead of `height_tree` and `height` if you only want the tree-height method to be part of the public API, but other than naming, I think this is already good.

Comment: @user2357112: thanks for your reply. very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sentinel object:

```
sentinel = object()

def height(self, node=sentinel)
    if node is sentinel:
       node = self._root
    ...
```

Since such object would have a unique memory address, it would never be identical to any other object (including `None`).

Answer (score 0):

You can always create arbitrary sentinels:

```
SENTINEL = object()

class BTree: 

    def __init__(self, node=None):
        self._root = node

    def height_tree(self):
        return self.height(self._root)

    def height(self, node=SENTINEL):
        if node is SENTINEL:
            node = self._root
        elif node is not None:
            height = max(self.height(node.get_left()), self.height(node.get_right())) + 1
        else:
            height = 0
        return height
```